# 301 redirection showing "The page isn't redirecting properly" error

Tags: php, seo, smarty, http-redirect

In my website I am giving a dummy URL for SEO purpose.My link is like below

```
http://legacy.com/project/491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore
```

In this URL women-tops-long-red-bangalore this wordings is dummy, based on the item id(491) the page is loading.After 491/{whatever you will give it will work}.

for this purpose I want to redirect the page.If some one give

```
 http://legacy.com/project/491/{any}
```

want to redirect to

```
 http://legacy.com/project/491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore
```

I given the below code

```
  if(isset($_GET['item_id']))
         {
           Header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
           Header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$project_link);   
        }
```

in $project_link I am calling a function it will return a string based on item id like the below

```
 "/project/491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore"
```

but it showing error  "The page isn't redirecting properly" But the url is changing

Comment: Your new URL would also come under  `http://legacy.com/project/491/{any}` and would redirect again wouldn't it? You should check if the URL is that, and not redirect again.

Comment: No its not redirecting if i give http://legacy.com/project/491/women url changing http://legacy.com/project/491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore like this but its showing  error

Comment: It won't go anywhere because you're in a redirect loop. I guess you are trying this in Firefox? Open the same url in Chrome, the error message will be more obvious

Comment: in chrome error "This web page has a redirect loop"

Comment: yes what is that redierct loop means how i can solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://legacy.com/project/491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore
```

matches the pattern

```
http://legacy.com/project/491/{any}
```

which redirects to:

```
http://legacy.com/project/491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore
```

which matches the pattern:

```
http://legacy.com/project/491/{any}
```

which redirects to:

```
http://legacy.com/project/491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore
```

which matches the pattern:

```
http://legacy.com/project/491/{any}
```

...

Rather than enforcing that url, I would negate the duplicate content issue by adding a canonical tag to the head of the page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://legacy.com/project/491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore">
```

Or you can break the loop in PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['item_id']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $project_link)
{
    Header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    Header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$project_link);   
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. This element doesn't change the url, but informs search engines that no matter how many variations of /491/{blah} they see, they all are really /491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore. This will prevent (possible) multiple urls creating duplicate content issues and a loss of search rank

Comment: if i give like this http://legacy.com/project/491/women when page is loading. But the url is not changing to this http://legacy.com/project/491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore

Comment: ok fine but our seo team want to be redirect to the original URL http://legacy.com/project/491/women-tops-long-red-bangalore

Comment: Ok, if you HAVE to have that url in the browser bar, then you can use PHP to prevent the loop. Check out the edit.

Comment: 1 more doubt i also tried this in if condition I am not added this one  && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $project_link but for me its not working tell me the reson

Comment: You've most likely got an extra (or missing) slash in $project_link. var_dump() the $_SERVER and $project_link variables and take a look